# Taking logarithm in limits

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I know that, when facing a limit like this: $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$$ then I can do this step: $$\ln\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n \right) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\right)$$ but is there a theorem that allows me to do this?

(There obviously is, but we haven't mentioned something of the like in class, and I want to be able to justify this step whenever I do it)

Comment: Most likely it's just because $$x\to\infty\implies\ln(x)\to\infty$$

Comment: Have you talked about continuity in your class? If you have, you've probably mentioned at some point that limits "commute" with continuous functions. In this case, $\ln(x)$ is continuous, so the limit can be put inside or outside.

Comment: @RhysHughes Yes but, as x→∞, (x/x+1)^x → some real number, so how can I use the fact you mentioned?

Comment: @Clayton yes we did, and i knew about that ''commutative'' rule of continuous functions, just didn't know how to phrase it formally as a theorem.

Comment: Formally, the theorem would say something like: Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Then for any convergent sequence $\{a_n\}\subseteq\Bbb R$ with limit $L$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=f(L)$. (Note that the theorem can be generalized a fair amount, but this form of the theorem is sufficient for most purposes in introductory courses.)

Answer (score 0):

Continuity allows bringing a function in or out of a limit.

If $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x) = L$, and $f$ is continuous at $L$, then 
$\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = f\left(\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)\right)$.

Here $a$ can be real or $\pm\infty$.

This is just because if $f$ is continuous at $L$, then $\lim\limits_{y\to L} f(y)=f(L)$.

Comment: That was what I was looking for, thanks